# How may I write a system of $n$ linear equations in matrix form that does not require a $n\times n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I want to write the system of linear equations

\begin{align}
y_1 &= \mathbf{x}_1'(\mathbf{a}/3 + \mathbf{b}/3 + \mathbf{c}/3), \\
y_2 &= \mathbf{x}_2'(\mathbf{a}/4 + \mathbf{b}/4 + \mathbf{c}/4 + \mathbf{d}/4), \\
y_3 &=\mathbf{x}_3'(\mathbf{c}/2 + \mathbf{d}/2), 
\end{align}

as the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\y_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_1'(\mathbf{a}/3 + \mathbf{b}/3 + \mathbf{c}/3) \\
\mathbf{x}_2'(\mathbf{a}/4 + \mathbf{b}/4 + \mathbf{c}/4 + \mathbf{d}/4) \\
\mathbf{x}_3'(\mathbf{c}/2 + \mathbf{d}/2) 
\end{bmatrix},$
where $\mathbf{x}_i$, $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, and $\mathbf{d}$ are $p\times 1$ vectors. Denote $n=3$.

Right now, I can do this as $\mathbf{y}=\text{diag}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{L}\mathbf{W}),$ where
$\mathbf{y}_{n\times1}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{X}_{n\times p}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}'_1\\
\mathbf{x}_2'\\
\mathbf{x}_3'
\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{L}_{p\times q}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a} & \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{c} & \mathbf{d}
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\mathbf{W}_{4\times n}=\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/4 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/4 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/4 & 1/2\\
0 & 1/4 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$.

However, the computation of $\mathbf{XLW}$ is incredibly intensive as $n\to\infty $. Right now, I set $n=3$ for ease of demonstration, but my $n$ is likely 500+). It seems computationally inefficient to compute an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{XLW}$ just to use its diagonal.

**My question:** Is there a more computationally efficient way to obtain the desired matrix equation?

Comment: @Mike I hope it's easier to follow. Aside from $n,p,q$, no suggestions were made, so I did what I think best. I also added my question in very clear terms.

Comment: What part of the RHS actually needs to be a matrix? A matrix is a representation of a map between two spaces. The output space here seems to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, but what should the input be? Is this an equation for $x$? $a,b,c$? If you are worried about computational efficiency, why multiply by $X$ at all? Just take inner products with the $i$-th column of $LW$ with $x_i$.